# Что за плагины используются для слайдера?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка, плагин

Кто знает каким плагином реализован [этот слайдер](https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/4417766/detail.aspx?targetUrl=GP) и что использовать чтобы при наведении на фотку она увеличивалась словно под лупой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данном сайте слайдер — это jCarusel. А для увеличения фото используется этот плагин:
https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/examples/